# Is it possible to get number of how many requests were received via throttling classes in django rest framework?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, throttling, rate

As title says, is it possible to get number of how many requests were received via throttling classes in django rest framework? For more information, for throttle classes I am using UserRateThrottle, for authentication classes I'm using TokenAuthentication, for permission classes I am using IsAuthenticated. I only have been able to get the limit number for example 1000/day. I did try to find the solution on google but I am out of luck! Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not out of the box, but you can easily implement a solution yourself.

[`UserRateThrottle`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/throttling.py#L183) is a subclass of `SimpleRateThrottle`, which contains methods [`throttle_success`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/throttling.py#L134) and [`throttle_failure`](https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/throttling.py#L143)

You can re-implement both and add in your own logic for logging, storing a counter in cache, or something else via

```
def throttle_success(self):
    log.info("throttle success")
    # alternatively, increment a counter somewhere

    # call super implementation
    super().throttle_success()
```

Comment: Hey, thank you for your answer, weird that they didn't add that, well at least it's possible to implement it "manually". I have tried finding the field or method that would give me access to it via dir() function but no luck. Well at least I know what path to go for :)! Thanks!

Comment: Most likely because the devs feel that this is better left to API/project monitoring and aggregate the responses by error code.